# how combine innerjoin query and 2 replace query in 1 query?

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart

I'm trying to combine 3 queries for building a search menu in opencart, but they always fail and error.

This is example query

First query:

```
SELECT p.product_id,
      (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total        
         FROM review r1        
        WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id        
          AND r1.status = '1'
        GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating
  FROM product p       
           LEFT JOIN  product_description pd 
                ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
           LEFT JOIN product_to_store p2s 
                ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
 WHERE pd.language_id = '1'       
   AND p.status = '1'       
   AND p.date_available <= NOW()       
   AND p2s.store_id = '0'       
   AND ( LCASE(pd.name) LIKE '%dellxps13%'            
         OR MATCH(pd.tag) AGAINST('dellxps13')           
       )
    OR LCASE(p.model) = 'dellxps13'       
    OR LCASE(p.sku) = 'dellxps13'       
    OR LCASE(p.upc) = 'dellxps13'       
    OR LCASE(p.ean) = 'dellxps13'       
    OR LCASE(p.jan) = 'dellxps13'       
    OR LCASE(p.isbn) = 'dellxps13'       
    OR LCASE(p.mpn) = 'dellxps13'       
 GROUP BY p.product_id       
 ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC
 LIMIT 0, 15
```

Second query:

```
SELECT REPLACE (model," ","") AS 'FIND' 
  FROM product 
 WHERE REPLACE (model," ","")
```

It's change to `p.model(for innerjoin, p.model = product.model)`

Third query:

```
SELECT REPLACE (name," ","") AS 'FIND2' 
  FROM product_description 
 WHERE REPLACE (name," ","")
```

It's change to `pd.name(for innerjoin, pd.name = product_description.name)`.

So I want replace all first, then `select from replace like '%dellxps13%'`

Anyone know how to combine 3 this query?

This is what I try to change and got error

```
AND ((LCASE(SELECT REPLACE (pd.name," ","")) FROM product_description 
WHERE LCASE (REPLACE (pd.name," ",""))) LIKE '%dellxps13%'            
     OR MATCH(pd.tag) AGAINST('dellxps13')           
   )
   OR LCASE((SELECT REPLACE (p.model," ","")) FROM product WHERE LCASE  (REPLACE (p.model," ",""))) = 'dellxps13'
```

error 1064 'SELECT REPLACE (pd.name," ","")) FROM product_description
WHERE LCASE (REPLAC' at line 16.

And when I not use LCASE got error

```
SELECT p.product_id,
      (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total        
         FROM review r1        
        WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id        
          AND r1.status = '1'
        GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating
  FROM product p       
           LEFT JOIN  product_description pd 
                ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
           LEFT JOIN product_to_store p2s 
                ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
 WHERE pd.language_id = '1'       
   AND p.status = '1'       
   AND p.date_available <= NOW()       
   AND p2s.store_id = '0'       
   AND ((SELECT REPLACE (pd.name," ","") FROM pd WHERE REPLACE (pd.name," ","") LIKE '%dellxps13%')         
    OR MATCH(pd.tag) AGAINST('dellxps13'))
    OR (SELECT REPLACE (p.model," ","") FROM p WHERE REPLACE (p.model," ","") LIKE '%dellxps13%')       
    OR LCASE(p.sku) = 'dellxps13'       
    OR LCASE(p.upc) = 'dellxps13'       
    OR LCASE(p.ean) = 'dellxps13'       
    OR LCASE(p.jan) = 'dellxps13'       
    OR LCASE(p.isbn) = 'dellxps13'       
    OR LCASE(p.mpn) = 'dellxps13'       
 GROUP BY p.product_id       
 ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC
 LIMIT 0, 15
```

error : 1146 - Table 'example.pd' doesn't exist

Comment: As you are using it in your second and third queries, `REPLACE` is just the name of a function.  You can call it in your main query, too, much like you call the `LCASE` function.

Comment: If you want us to speak to the errors you are getting, then you'll need to present a query that in fact elicits an error message, and the message.  That might help clarify what you are trying to achieve, too.  As the question now stands, it's unclear to me exactly how you hope to use the `REPLACE()` function.

Comment: I should have been more clear: whatever code and message you want us to look at, present it **in the question.**  There is an "edit" link just below the tags that you can use for the purpose.